# Angular test not seeing types

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm using @types/fhir and while the JIT and AOT see the `fhir` namespace fine, running `ng test` doesn't. How can I debug this?

My `tsconfig.json` already has `"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]` in it.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/fhir": "0.0.30",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/fhir": "0.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

`karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: How does your package.json look like with AOT and ng test?

Comment: Added package.json!

Comment: Seems alright take a look in your **karma.conf** there are the configs for ng test.

Comment: Updated. It should be the default from Angular CLI. I'm not sure what to look for in here

Comment: `"test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",`

In package.json for more info read  https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your .angular-cli.json, there can be "testTsconfig" property which leads to another tsconfig (tsconfig.spec.json). In that file you can specify  fhir in types array.